# Python3 import psycopg2 failure

Tags: sql, python-3.x, psycopg2

I'm new to python and psycopg2. It shoots an error when I try to import sys and psycopg2. Can anyone kindly suggest a solution?

Error message:

```
C02QM3FSFVH3:q6 kwunkeilau$ ./q6 'Australia' 2006 
./q6: line 4: import: command not found
./q6: line 5: import: command not found
./q6: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./q6: line 7: `def team_check(cur, team):'
C02QM3FSFVH3:q6 kwunkeilau$ which python3
/Users/kwunkeilau/anaconda3/bin/python3
```

My file

```
# !/Users/kwunkeilau/anaconda3/bin/python3

import sys
import psycopg2

def team_check(cur, team):
    q = "select * from Teams where country = %s"
    .....
```

[my file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fieFl.png)

Comment: What does `q6` look like? Paste the first few lines, including the shebang line if any.

Comment: Yep I copied to above

Comment: There should be no spaces between `#` and `!`. Your shell thinks that it's a shell script.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.